# How do I get my slick carousel to show more than 1 image? Also, how come my arrows don't show up?

Tags: html, jquery, slick.js

I'm having a hard time get the slick carousel to work. I'm new to coding, I just started learning recently and I can't seem to get anything to work properly. I'm creating a super simple portfolio since I'm about finished my major in university, I wanted a slider to help show batches of my projects.

I'll drop my code below, but as of now I'm having a hard time getting more than just the first cover image to show up. When I click the dots to move to the next picture, nothing appears. I also can't get the arrows to appear, even though I've tried changing the colour to see them better. I might have done something wrong, but the dots of the slider also appear elsewhere on screen in comparison to the images (they appear at the center of my page in between other containers I've placed). I've tried recreating the document with just the slider and had the same issues so I know I'm doing something wrong with slick and nothing else is interfering.

I'd really appreciate some help!! :D

HTML(slick):

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/processpages.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <link href="scripts/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheets" media="screen"/>
    <link href="scripts/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#slick").slick({
                 dots:true,
                 arrows: true,
                 centerMode: true,
                 autoplaySpeed:2500,
                 fade:true,
                 slidesToShow: 1,
                 infinate: true,
                adaptiveHeight: true
                //  slidesToShow:2,
                //  slidesToScroll:2,
             });
        });
        </script>
</head>
```

HTML(DIV):

```
    <div id="slick">
    <div><img class="slider" src="assets/GRPH_AnalogSketches1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img class="slider" src="assets/GD_Sketch3test4.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img class="slider" src="assets/failSketch2_audacity.png" /></div>
    <div><img class="slider" src="assets/gd_FACEsketch1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img class="slider" src="assets/whiteTest.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: @Grumpy How do I find that? ;-; I'm sorry, this is all so new.

Comment: @Grumpy NVM!! A friend of mine said it's probably a "logic error" (whatever that means). Because there are no errors being displayed.